# EF Core code-first entities for marketplace

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core MVC & EF Core project as my first learning experience. As an example, I took `funpay.com`, a marketplace of gaming services.

I don't need all the functionality. I want to make just a list of games and go to services specifically for each game.

For example Diablo (Gold, Account, Boosting), when I go to Gold, I get to a separate page with offers.

At the stage of planning database entities I'm already stalled.

Do I need a separate entity for these services (Gold, acc .et.c)? Or just links to a blank page.

As it turned out just thinking through the structure is the hardest part.

Something like this?

```
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public Game Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. `Game` has many `Service`s, and `Service` have their own properties. But you need to make sure what kinda properties should these two hold - the step where you clarify the requirements - to design it with more details. However, thinking too much beforehand might result in eventually unused things, or stalling out the passion for making the application. So I'd recommend don't think too long, once you figure out something that makes you "Hey, this might work.", do it, then during the implementation you'll learn from experience, while you actually made things.